# How to check whether an instance of a superclass is a subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, methods

I am working on a school project that involves a parking lot. Our 'parking lot' contains a 10x10 grid and each space can either contain a vehicle, or be empty.

I have a superclass of vehicles and multiple subclasses of the vehicle class, such as motorbikes and vans that inherit attributes and methods from the superclass.

I have a method which returns a linked list of all the neighbours of each parking space. However the linked list stores the objects as the superclass type vehicle, no matter what subclass the object actually is.

I want to add methods that are dependent on what subclass of vehicles is a neighbour of a given spot ie whether it contains a motorbike or not.

How would I go about implementing this in my project?
Thanks in advance.

I was expecting to be able to get the subclass type of each vehicle in the linked list but could not.

Comment: wdym with `add methods that are dependent on what subclass of vehicles is a neighbour` ?

Comment: the project i am doing is similar to a cellular automaton. there are rules such that if there are too many of a certain type of vehicle in an area around a spot, other vehicles cannot park there, hence i need to be able to get the subclass type of the vehicle

Comment: you can get the subclass using `v.getClass()` and check on the name OR create a property (maybe a `enum`) to perform this operation

Comment: you can also test if some object is an instance of a given Class by using `instanceof` (e.g. `if (obj instanceof MotorBike) { ... }`) but the more Object Oriented solution is using methods like having each Vehicle having a `getType()` or `isMotorBike()` method